# An anthropology of "corporations are bad"

Tags: anthropology

I am just wondering if a lot of Wikipedia articles reflect a majority cultural bias, and sometimes trying to note what they may be.

I sometimes think it is very common to malign corporations. I am wondering if there have been any anthropological analyses of this.

My understanding of an "anthropological analysis" is an attempt to realize the dynamics of a culture - especially when you realize that something is not necessarily a default. In a certain sense of the word, this can be considered a type of "recognition".

Thus, it is not to argue what is true or false (i.e., "are corporations bad"), but to recognize what often passes as unnoticeable because normal.

Comment: Give examples? Most of the time, if Wikipedia is saying something bad about a corporation, it's because the corporation did something bad that made the news. Wikipedia just reports the news. Corporations do bad things because they optimize for profit and therefore cut whatever safety/pollution/dishonesty/etc corners they think they can get away with.

Comment: @causative, corporations do bad things because they are run by human beings and human beings do bad things. Individuals are no less motivated by their own self interest than corporations are.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Corporations can be sued by investors if they fail to maximize profit. They have a fiduciary duty to their shareholders that they can be sued about if they don't squeeze out maximum profit. Also, CEOs have higher rates of psychopathy than the general population.

Comment: @causative I very much doubt investors can (successfully) sue a corporation for *not* cutting "safety/pollution/dishonesty/etc corners". I doubt any reasonable court would find that someone had a legal duty to put people's safety at risk or lie in any official or legal context (pollution may be a bit more questionable). Although investors have significant say over how a company is run, and by who.

Comment: This isn't about philosophy. This is a sociology question. Anthropology is a primarily social science with ties to biology.

Comment: aren't corporations all about "individual profit without individual responsibility"? *of course* they're evil

Comment: @ac15, no corporations are about limiting liability. Without limited liability any lawsuit against a corporation would have all of the investors severally liable for a judgment. No one is going to invest in a business under those conditions unless they are personally involved in it. The modern world would not exist under those conditions. There would be no car manufacturers, no medical equipment manufacturers, no electronics. It is all made possible by limited liability corporations.